# Properties of the operator $T: f\to f*g$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, convolution

Let g be the characteristic function of [-1/2,1/2].

$T: f\to f*g$ (convolution).

I have managed to prove that T is a linear,bounded,self adjoint,injective operator and it's immage is inclused in the space $H^1(R)$. Can anyone help me to find out if  T is also compact/surjective? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This [should help](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411196/how-to-prove-that-operator-is-not-compact-in-l-2-mathbbr?rq=1) you.

Comment: Which norm is involved?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: the norm of $L^2(R)$

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier to do this calculation in Fourier space:
$$ \widehat{Tf}(\xi) = \hat g(\xi) \hat g(\xi) .$$
And the Fourier transform is an isometry on $L^2$.  So look at the operator
$$ S f(x) = \hat g(x) f(x) $$
and derive all the properties that way instead.